# Import .RTF file to Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, rtf

```
import sys
import os.path

from pyth.plugins.rtf15.reader import Rtf15Reader
from pyth.plugins.xhtml.writer import XHTMLWriter


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
else:
    filename = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), 
        'HW1_TRPL_Stranks.rtf'))

doc = Rtf15Reader.read(open(filename, "r"))

print(XHTMLWriter.write(doc, pretty=True).read())
```

Anyone knows how to import a .rtf file to python? I'm trying something from stack but it doesn't work.

Update: I installed pyth module and it keeps telling me module not found
[`This is the error I got`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ireiu.png)

Comment: If you are using python 3, you need parentheses around your value for the print statement

Comment: I fixed that and install pyth but its saying it can't find module "pyth"

Answer (score 0):

pyth doesn't have python 3 support, as noted [here](https://github.com/brendonh/pyth/issues/32), but someone made a fork [here](https://github.com/prechelt/pyth/tree/pyth-py3).

Answer (score 0):

From the several options proposed around stackoverflow, the most reliable in my opinion is using command line LibreOffice.

The command in shell should by:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to html file.rtf
```

in case you want to convert to html and not loose formating. `txt` would also be an option.

In Python3.6 you would have

```
from subprocess import call
call(["soffice", "--headless", "--convert-to", "html", "file.rtf"])
```

then read the file to a variable:

```
with open('file.html', 'r') as myfile: 
   data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Important note: this won't work if any instance of LibreOffice is open. So, before running it, close all LibreOffice files.